# Residues and blow ups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-manifolds, several-complex-variables

On a 2-dimensional complex manifold consider two functions which are meromorphic with singularities along two divisors which meet at a point. There is a residue from these meromorphic functions (strictly 2-forms to make them well defined) at the point of intersection.

We could also blow up the point of intersection to $\mathbb{CP}^1$. What connection is there between the blow up and the meromorphic functions? In particular, is there a construction on the blow up given by the meromorphic functions (e.g. a construction of sections of a line bundle??) which naturally gives the residue?

Apologies, I am not an algebraic geometer and am finding my way around this subject. I am looking at applications to integrable systems, and require a way to look at the residue as a purely point construction, rather than associated to the original divisors….

Comment: I saw your question initially, but I didn't understand what you meant by "residue which is a 2-from...". I understand you're not an algebraic geometer, but it would helpful if you include an example of what you have in mind. Usually, it's the other way around: given a differential form with singularities, you can take the residue of that. For the first part, blowing up a point won't change the field of meromorphic functions.

Comment: Sorry, you are right - in one dimension it means that the residue is a vector! I will edit this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I want to clarify the concept of the residue that you're thinking of to algebraic geometers: Start with a complex manifold $X$, and two smooth divisors $D_1$ and $D_2$ meeting transversely. Suppose $\phi$ is a meromorphic two forms on $X$ with poles along $D_1$ and $D_2$, it make sense to talk about the double residue $Res_{D_1,D_2}\phi$. This will be a holomorphic function on $D_1\cap D_2$.

This can be thought as a two-step residue, first take residue along $D_1$, one get a meromoprhic 1-form $\phi_1=Res_{D_1}\phi$ on $D_1$ with pole along $D_1\cap D_2$. Then take reside $Res_{D_1\cap D_2}\phi_1$. (One can also first take residue along $D_2$ then $D_1$.)

Second, I want to try to interpret your question. Maybe you want to ask

"*Suppose $\dim X=2$, what is the relationship between the double residue $Res_{D_1,D_2}\phi$ and the residue of the pullback of $\phi$ on the blowup $Bl_{D_1\cap D_2}X$?*"

This doesn't really depend on the dimension of $X$, but for simplicity let me assume $X$ is two dimensional, and working locally, we can assume it is a ball around origin of $\mathbb C^2$, and $D_1=\{z_1=0\}$, $D_2=\{z_2=0\}$. $\phi(z_1,z_2)=f(z_1,z_2)dz_1\wedge dz_2$, and $f(z_1,z_2)$ is a meromorphic function. We write $f(z_1,z_2)$ as Lorent serizes

$$\sum_{i,j} \frac{a_{ij}}{z_1^iz_2^j}=\cdots+\frac{a_{11}}{z_1z_2}+\cdots$$

Here, I only write the term of interest. The double residue on $X$ is   $$Res_{D_1,D_2}\phi=Res_{z_2=0}(\sum_{j}\frac{a_{1,j}}{z_2^j})=a_{11}.$$

Now, on the blowup $\tilde{X}$, there are three divisors $\tilde{D}_1,\tilde{D}_2$, $E$, where the first two are proper transforms and the last one is the exceptional divisor. Let $\tilde{\phi}$ be the pullback. One can take residue $Res_{E}\tilde{\phi}$, which will be a meromorphic 1-form on $E$, and then consider the double residue at the two intersections $\tilde{D}_1\cap E$ and $\tilde{D}_2\cap E$. In one affine coordinate, $z_2=z_1u$, $\tilde{\phi}(z_1,u)=\phi(z_1,z_1u)=\sum_{i,j}\frac{a_{ij}}{z_1^{i+j}u^j}z_1dz_1\wedge du$. So $Res_{E}\tilde{\phi}$ is to take residue at $u=0$, which only pick up term involving $\frac{1}{u}$, so the residue one-form is $$Res_{E}\tilde{\phi}=\sum_{i}\frac{a_{i1}}{z_1^{i}}dz_1.$$ Then the resulting double residue at $\tilde{D}_1\cap E$ picks up $i=1$ term and $Res_{E,\tilde{D}_1}\tilde{\phi}=a_{11}$. Similarly, in the other affine chart, $Res_{E,\tilde{D}_2}\tilde{\phi}=a_{11}$.

So we can say the double residue on $X$ and the double residue (in two ways) on the blowup $\tilde{X}$ are the same.

Comment: Thanks, that looks very useful. As a slight additional question (to save spending another 300 reputation): Are there exact sequences for cohomology or relative cohomology involving the residues? Where could I look for information on this? (Remembering that I am not an expert - sheaves etc. are OK, lots of background on algebraic geometry probably not...)

Comment: Yes, Suppose $D$ is a smooth divisor in $X$, and $U=X\setminus D$, then there is a residue map $$H_{dR}^k(U)\to H_{dR}^{k-1}(D)$$ by sending a meromorphic $k$-form $\phi$ on $X$ with pole along $D$ to a $k-1$ form $Res(\phi)$ on $D$. Locally, let $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ be the coordinate and $D$ is defined by $x_1=0$. By Griffiths, $\phi$ is cohomologous to a smooth form with log pole, i.e., can be written as $\eta\wedge \frac{d{z_1}}{z_1}$ for $\eta$ a smooth $k-1$ form. Then $Res(\phi)=\eta$.

Comment: Use the Thom isomophism $H^{k+1}(X,U)\cong H^{k-1}(D)$. The residue map is actually the same as the coboundary map $H^k(U)\to H^{k+1}(X,U)$ for the long exact sequence of the pair $(X,U)$.

Comment: I learned this from Griffiths' paper "On the periods of certain rational integrals. I". The relevant materials are on p.490. It's a long paper, but it is all about complex analysis and doesn't really need too much background in algebraic geometry. Voisin's book "Hodge theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry, vol. I", pp. 211-212, also has related discussion.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful!